# Elasticsearch NGram Analyser - Change the Order of the results of Query

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch Query change display results according to the scoring

The current Query gives the result of the Field title in the following order.

1. Quick 123
2. Foxes Quick
3. Quick
4. Foxes Quick Quick
5. Quick Foxes

Shouldn't 
3. Quick be coming as a first result instead?

Also , Foxes Quick Quick has two occurances of Quick, it should have some preference in the Queried result . But it is coming at 4th poistion .

Index Settings .

```
 {
 "fundraisers": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "fundraisers",
        "creation_date": "1546515635025",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
            },
            "search_analyzer_search": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "search_tokenizer_search"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ],
              "min_gram": "3",
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "max_gram": "50"
            },
            "search_tokenizer_search": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "whitespace"
              ],
              "min_gram": "3",
              "type": "ngram",
              "max_gram": "50"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "mVweO4_sT3Ww00MzdLyavw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020399"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Query 

GET fundraisers/_search?explain=true

{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": {
        "query": "qui",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
    }
  }
}
Mapping
{
  "fundraisers": {
    "mappings": {
      "fundraisers": {
        "properties": {
          "status": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          },
          "twitterUrl": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "videoLinks": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "zipCode": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I complicating this too much by using match_phrase,search analyzer and ngrams or is there any simpler way to achieve the expected result ?

Ref: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: To understand the scoring, add `"explain": true` to the query dsl.

Comment: Thanks @NishantSaini.I already added that in the Query . Its showing the response of explain . How do we alter the order of the response ?

Comment: @ShivaMSK , could you provide o/p of explain API ? I can't see it in your question

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal 
The explain api computes a score explanation for a query and a specific document.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Comment: @ShivaMSK I know that I want to know the output it produces in ur case.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal
Please find the response of the query here . 
http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=28134e8c0dbf48e0be62588fd394e309

Comment: Please add your mapping and not just the index settings; it's unclear what analyzer is set on `title`. Ideally make it a fully runnable example (mapping + example docs + query), so people can easily help you. Also the combination of `match_phrase`, a search analyzer, and probably ngrams is quite a bit — not sure this is making your life too easy.

Comment: @xeraa Added the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first let's create a minimal and reproducible setup:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
          },
          "search_analyzer_search": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "search_tokenizer_search"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "my_tokenizer": {
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit"
            ],
            "min_gram": "3",
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "max_gram": "50"
          },
          "search_tokenizer_search": {
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit",
              "whitespace"
            ],
            "min_gram": "3",
            "type": "ngram",
            "max_gram": "50"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "title": "Quick 123"
}
PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "title": "Foxes Quick"
}
PUT test/_doc/3
{
  "title": "Quick"
}
PUT test/_doc/4
{
  "title": "Foxes Quick Quick"
}
PUT test/_doc/5
{
  "title": "Quick Foxes"
}
```

Then let's try the simplest query:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "qui"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And now your order is:

1. Quick
2. Foxes Quick Quick
3. Quick 123
4. Foxes Quick
5. Quick Foxes

That's pretty much what you were expecting, right? There might be other usecases, which are not covered by this query, but IMO you'll have to use `multi_match` and search on different analyzers, because I'm not sure a `phrase_search` on an edgegram makes much sense.